# Why Cubes falls through the floor but Player sphere dose not?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Start passing first tutorial "Roll-a-Ball", and at the stage #3 "Collecting, Scoring and Building the game", I saw an interesting thing without explanation:

Both "Player" and "Pick Up" have "Rigid Body component attached" and have Use Gravity checkbox selected.
But "Player" sphere dose not falls thought "Ground" mesh, but "Pick Up" cubes dose.

Why it happens?

here is moment in video: 
https://youtu.be/XtR29MmzuT0?t=14m35s

Comment: The Pick Up is configured to be a trigger, so it dosn't collide with objects. In the video they unchecked the `Use Gravity` Option maybe you didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`BoxCollider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider.html) on the pick up prefab is marked as a trigger (i.e. `IsTrigger` is set to `true`). A trigger collider behaves as a *volume or space* in the world, unlike regular colliders which represent an actual physical entity. A trigger collider does not interact with the world, but raises events when a [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) enters/exits/stays in the volume in the world represented by it.